# Формулировка о присвоении знака

Tags: дефект, предложение, локализация

В списке пользователей, получивших знаки, например, [Любознательный](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/87/curious), указано:

> Присвоен {КОГДА} для
>
> [image: присвоен для]

В transifex полной строки не обнаружено, но есть [2 варианта](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40263969?q=Awarded%20%24relativeTime%24) для первой части строки (если она склеивается). И отдельно обнаружилось для [to/для](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40263959?key=2177f4fdd144e4a6fe0e71858190672c).

В текущем виде выглядит странно и не по-русски.

Связанный вопрос на MSE: [Don't split sentence about badge awarding](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297679/339911)

Answer (score 5):

Предлагаю убрать слово "для" вовсе.

Comment: А оно точно больше нигде не используется?

Comment: @Qwertiy посмотрите вопрос на MSE (ссылку добавил в тело текущего вопроса).

Answer (score 3):

Предлагаю заменить слово "для" на "участнику".

Comment: Вот возьмут все для на сайте, да в участников превратятся)))

Comment: @Qwertiy конечно отдельно "to" нельзя переводить так. Надо чтобы текст был един, а не склеен из отдельных слов.